# System.OutOfMemoryException Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am working on a legacy system where the end users reported exception while loading a page. This is developend in ASP.NET 2.0 and Oracle.DataAccess. The exception is not reproducible in any of the staging or development servers, and is not consistent (i.e. sometime works and some not).

The exception is as follows:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Int32 cb) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Char() at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

The way it calls in the data access layers are as follows, removed some parameters to just to get the flow clear,

```
public void GetXXXData(UserCredentials credentials, 
                       decimal? P_IN_ID, 
                       string P_IN_TYPE, 
                       out string[] P_OUT_XX_ID, 
                       out string[] P_OUT_XX_NAME, 
                       int? outputArrayLength)
{
    if (outputArrayLength == null)
    {
        outputArrayLength = 3000;  
    }

    OdacCmd cmd = null;    
    P_OUT_XX_ID = null;
    P_OUT_XX_NAME = null;
    cmd = OdacFactory.CreateCommand("PK_XX_QAS1.pr_xx_data_q", credentials);

    cmd.AddParam("P_IN_ID", P_IN_ID);
    cmd.AddParam("P_IN_QUAL_TYPE", P_IN_TYPE);
    IDataParameter param_P_OUT_XX_ID = cmd.AddOutputParameterString("P_OUT_XX_ID", 
        outputArrayLength.Value);
    IDataParameter param_P_OUT_XX_NAME = cmd.AddOutputParameterString("P_OUT_XX_NAME", 
        outputArrayLength.Value);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    P_OUT_XX_ID = OdacFactory.GetStringArray(param_P_OUT_XX_ID.Value);
    P_OUT_XX_NAME = OdacFactory.GetStringArray(param_P_OUT_XX_NAME.Value);
}
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Update::

In OdacCmd the connection is disposing as follows

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_reader != null)
        {
            _reader.Close();
            _reader.Dispose();
            _reader = null;
        }

        if (_ownsConnection)
        {
            OracleConnection connection = _cmd.Connection;
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
                _cmd.Connection = null;
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _cmd.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

and In ExecuteNonQuery connection closes as follows,

```
   public int ExecuteNonQuery()
    {
        if (_ownsConnection)
        {
            _cmd.Connection.Open();
        }
        try
        {
            return _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_ownsConnection)
            {
                _cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that this might happen because connection/command objects are not properly disposed of, do you have `using` blocks around the connection object in the `OdacFactory` or wherever the connection is managed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have updated your queries,